# Internal links in DokuWiki with markdownextra plugin to match Trunbk Notes syntax

Tags: ios, wiki, markdown, dokuwiki

I want to use DokuWiki as a desktop frontend to wiki files generated with the iOS app
[Trunk Notes](http://appsonthemove.com/trunk.htm). I have installed the [markdownextra plugin](http://madpropellerhead.com/projects/php-markdown-extra-plugin-for-dokuwiki) hoping to make DokuWiki compatible with Trunk Notes.

My problem now is that internal links typed in **Trunk Notes** syntax as

```
[[AnotherPage]]
```

do not work in **DokuWiki**. Because the links should remain workin in Trunk Notes I cannot change the link style to e.g. `[AnotherPage(?id=AnotherPage.md)` as suggested in the DokuWiki plugin user guide (scroll down to the end of the plugin page).

Any idea how to sort this out? Has anybody managed to get **DokuWiki** working with the files **Trunk Notes** generates including internal linking?